# How do I skip methods using @AfterMethod in TestNG

Tags: java, testng

I have a set of tests as follows.

```
@Test
public void testX(){
}

@Test
public void testY(){
}

@Test
public void testZ(){
}
```

I have another test which I should run after each of the test is executed.
I hope I could do that with

```
@AfterMethod
public void testA(){
}
```

Now I need to skip `testA` for `testX`. Which means I don't need `testA` to run after `testX`. How do I do it? Also how to specify multiple test cases to skip in the above manner?

Comment: Depending on order of test execution is what's fundamentally wrong at the first place. Tests should be standalone units.

Comment: These are integration tests. So I think the order matters

Comment: If the order matters, it's likely that the tests can't be decoupled and run individually - in such case, I think it's more readable and less error prone to simply have one @Test method.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do that would be to add to the same [group](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups) every method you want `testA` to execute.

In the following example, `testY` and `testZ` are added to the `"myGroup"` group so the `testA` after method, which also belongs to this group, will only be executed for those tests.

```
@Test
public void testX(){
}

@Test(groups = { "myGroup" })
public void testY(){
}

@Test(groups = { "myGroup" })
public void testZ(){
}

@AfterMethod(groups = { "myGroup" })
public void testA(){
}
```

Comment: what if already testX and testZ are in  two different groups?

Comment: @DesirePRG You can add a new custom group to each concerned method.

Comment: When added an @AfterX annotation testNG considers it a a configuration test. is there any way that i can tell it to consider as a normal test

Comment: @DesirePRG I'm not sure what you mean, there is no `@AfterX` annotation in my answer.

Comment: i mean "AfterMethod" or anything prefixed with "After"

Comment: @DesirePRG What do you mean by "configuration test"? What's a "normal test"?

Comment: @DesirePRG That tutorial does not mention "configuration test" or "normal test" so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: as you can see in the first example output it says only two test cases it ran and 0 failures. only the tests annotates with @Test are counted here. Others are considered to be configuration tests

Comment: @DesirePRG This is unrelated to adding `groups` to `AfterMethod`. It depends on your `testng.xml`. You should post a separate question for that.